# Encapsulation issue with delegates?

Tags: c#, oop, encapsulation

I'm wondering why this works?

For example I have some **executor class** that looks like so:

```
public class Executor
{
    public void Execute(Action action)
    {
        action();
    }
}
```

Now I have some **need to be executed class** that looks like:

```
public class NeedToBeExecuted
{
    public void Invoke()
    {
        Executor executor = new Executor();
        executor.Execute(DoSomething);
    }

    private void DoSomething()
    {
        // do stuff private
    }
}
```

My question is why this is work's I pass a **private method** to **other class**?

Is this not an encapsulation issue?

Comment: do we have an encapsulation issue when we define a method that is executed as ThreadRunner?

Comment: do stuff private ... good

Comment: You **are** passing the method as an `Action`. Although it is not exactly the same, think about if you were passing a *private* array or some class instance as a parameter to another method. There's nothing wrong with it. `DoSomething` will also be able to access the private variables from `NeedToBeExecuted` it uses because of closures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not a violation of encapsulation.

First off: the class itself is the thing that decided to hand out a delegate to one of its private methods!  The class has access to its private methods and if it chooses to hand a reference to one to code outside of the accessibility domain of that method, that's perfectly within its rights.

Second: the accessibility domain of a method doesn't restrict where the method can be *called*.  **It restricts where the method can be looked up by name**.  Class `Executor` is never using the *name* `DoSomething` to invoke the private method. It's using the name `action`.

Answer (score 3):

Let me give it a try then.

No we don't have an encapsulation issue. You are defining a class that is responsible to `Execute` something. The `Executer` knows **nothing** about what actually is executed. It only knows that it should execute `DoSomething`. What `DoSomething` does is specified in the class that is responsible to have something executed.

As I commented, it's quite similar to what you would do with a `Thread`. You define a method that needs to be executed on a different Thread. That's why the class has a Thread, and defines which method should be ran on that Thread. Thread still knows nothing about the class where it plays a role in.

The relations are Class => Thread. Not the other way around.

In your example, the relations are `NeedToBeExecuted` => `Executer`. Not the other way around.

The concept can be tricky to your mind, but you are doing nothing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It's only as much of an encapsulation issue as using reflection is. It's possible to get access to private methods and variables from an external class quite easily using reflection. You shouldn't consider this a bad thing necessarily as it just makes the language all that much more powerful.

The class is the one giving up the delegate method anyway, so in a way the class is enabling the behaviour so it shouldn't be an encapsulation issue at all.

Comment: but executer can't access private members of the NeedToBeExecuted class. It only receives a 'function pointer'. Encapsulation is not an issue here. Not like it 'could' be an issue with reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this: `NeedToBeExecuted` is not exposing the `DoSomething()` method in such a way that it can be called arbitrarily - instead it is passing it as a delegate to another function. It could just as easily be passing `() => DoSomething()` - the result is the same. Ultimately access modifiers are there to prevent a **different** class using your method, you are still free to use it as you like. If you choose to pass it to another class, that's a valid use.

Answer (score 1):

You pass `DoSomething` in the method `Invoke()`, and it is accessible in the context. There's no encapsulation issue.

However, as you see the comment in the code, `DoSomething` is not accessible in `EitherNeedToBeExecuted`.

```
public class Executor {
    public void Execute(Action action) {
        action();
    }
}

public class NeedToBeExecuted {
    public virtual void Invoke() {
        Executor executor=new Executor();
        executor.Execute(this.DoSomething);
    }

    private void DoSomething() {
        Console.WriteLine("I'M DOING IT MYSELF!!");
    }

    protected Executor m_Executor=new Executor();
}

public class EitherNeedToBeExecuted: NeedToBeExecuted {
    public override void Invoke() {
        // 'NeedToBeExecuted.DoSomething()' is inaccessible due to its protection level
        m_Executor.Execute(base.DoSomething);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulation means being able to change the internals of some module without changing external code. This is still the case here. So no encapsulation breach has occurred.

Comment: I find it interesting how different people view the purpose of encapsulation differently. Though encapsulation does provide insurance against taking a dependency on the details of a mechanism which could change, I view the fundamental purpose of encapsulation as *giving the programmer the ability to maintain an invariant that other code can in turn rely upon*.