# Why can a base class event call a private method?

Tags: c#, events, radix

I have a question regarding raising base class events. I am currently reading the MSDN C# Programming Guide and I cannot understand one thing from the below article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hy3sefw3.aspx

```
public void AddShape(Shape s)
{
    _list.Add(s);
    s.ShapeChanged += HandleShapeChanged;
}
```

OK, so we are registering the delegate with an event and we'll be calling the **private** method *HandleShapeChanged* when the event is raised.

```
public void Update(double d)
{
    radius = d;
    area = Math.PI * radius * radius;
    OnShapeChanged(new ShapeEventArgs(area));
}

protected override void OnShapeChanged(ShapeEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnShapeChanged(e);
}
```

And here we are calling the base class method *OnShapeChanged*, which, in success, will fire the event. But the event is based in the *Shape* class, so how can it access the method *HandleShapeChanged*, which is private?

I have just started to learn the language, so please bear with me. My understanding of this example may be well off target.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encapsulation issue with delegates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15586728/encapsulation-issue-with-delegates).  Quoting Eric Lippert's accepted answer: "The accessibility domain of a method doesn't restrict where the method can be called. It restricts where the method can be looked up by name."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I see the way you are thinking, it feels like another class is calling a private method.  But no, the best way to think about it is that access rules are checked when the delegate is **created**, not when it is invoked.  And that of course is no problem, the class can access its own private method.

Also checking it when it is invoked would be lousy, that would require making the event handler public.  And handling events is almost always a very private implementation detail of a class that no external code should ever be allowed to call directly.  Since that would mean that you couldn't be sure in your event handler that it was actually the event that triggered the call.  That's bad, very bad.

Answer (score 10):

The event is invoking the delegate. It doesn't matter what code is in the delegate. Since the method is not being invoked explicitly, access rules do not apply.

Note also that this has nothing to do with the fact that the event is in a base class. The exact same thing would happen even if the event were in a totally unrelated class.